# What is the benefit of blocking cookie for clicked link? (SameSite=strict)

Tags: google-chrome, http, security, cookies, browser

So for Google Chrome and Opera, cookies have `SameSite` attribute, which can have one of two values: `strict` or `lax`.

One of a few differences between those is that `SameSite=strict` will prevent a cookie from being sent when we click a link to another domain.

I know that `SameSite` is not W3C recommendation yet, but what is potential benefit of this behavior? I find it rather annoying, because the cookie is sent anyway when we refresh or click another link on the current domain. That leads to rather weird user experience - for example: we are logged out, then we click some domestic link or refresh and we are suddenly authenticated.

I'm aware that it's not designed for the greatest user experience, but rather for security. But what are we actually winning here in terms of security?

Answer (score 4):

There should be an answer here so I'm just going to repeat what's already been said in the comments.

You should always use `samesite=lax`, unless you're OK with giving your users a terrible user experience. `lax` is secure enough, as cookies will only be sent for [Safe Methods](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1) (i.e. GET) when referred from a different domain. If you do dangerous things with `GET` requests, well, you have bigger problems.

Answer (score 4):

The benefits of using `strict` instead of `lax` are limited. I can see two:

1. Protection against CSRF attacks via `GET` requests. Such attacks are not normally possible since they rely on the server implementing `GET` endpoints with side effects (incorrectly and in violation of the semantics specified by [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1)). An example was given by you in the comments:

   > Imagine we have a very bad design and all our actions are performed on GET method. The attacker placed link saying "Save puppies" which links to `http://oursite.com/users/2981/delete`. That's the only use-case I can think of - when we have some action done via GET method, while it shouldn't.
2. Protection against timing attacks. There's a class of attacks - which were already discovered [back in 2000](http://sip.cs.princeton.edu/pub/webtiming.pdf?fbclid=IwAR3X-kv3r5eDBY0TyMD_K4DsHABHpW1pO6b0kSv4vghayd1MS-p_5Tkr61U), but which [Mathias Bynens](https://fronteers.nl/congres/2016-spring/sessions/front-end-performance-the-dark-side-by-mathias-bynens) has recently explored and popularised - that involve a malicious webpage using JavaScript to initiate a request to a page on another domain and then measuring how long it takes, and inferring things about the user from the time taken. An example that Mathias invented is to initiate a request to a Facebook page with a [restricted audience](https://www.facebook.com/help/352402648173466), such that it is only accessible by, say, people in Examplestan. Then the evil webpage times how long it takes for the response to come back. Facebook serves the error page when you try to access an inaccessible post faster than it serves the actual post, so if the evil webpage gets a quick response, it can infer that the user is not in Examplestan; if it gets a *slow* response, then the user is probably an Examplestani.

Since browsers don't stop executing JavaScript on a page when you do top-level navigation until they've received a response from the URL being navigated to, these timing attacks are unfortunately perfectly possible with top-level navigation; your evil page can just navigate the user away via `location=whatever`, then time how long it takes for the other page to load by repeatedly recording the current timestamp to `localStorage` in a loop. Then on a subsequent visit the evil page can check how long the page took to start unloading, and infer the response time of the page being timed.

The domain hosting the target page - like facebook.com, in the case of Mathias's example - could protect its users from this kind of attack by using `samesite=strict` cookies.

Obviously, these limited benefits come at a serious UX tradeoff, and so are typically not worth it compared to the already-pretty-good protections offered by `samesite=lax`!